# contentEditable div cursor position is moving to end when setState

Tags: reactjs, contenteditable, setstate

I am trying to retain the cursor position whenever user manually go back and delete some
characters or add some character.

Currently, the cursor is not retaining position due to setState. How to fix this issue.

```
export default class MyEditor extends React.Component {      
         constructor(props) { this.state = {contentValue: ''}}
    
        onKeyDown = (e) => {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
            }
        
          setContentValue = (e) => {
            // some condition check
            this.inputRef.current.innerText = e.target.innerText;
            this.setState({contentValue: e.target.innerText})
         }
        
           render(){
               return(
                      <div className="mydiv"
                           contentEditable="true"
                           placeholder="Enter text"
                           suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
                           onInput={(e) => this.setContentValue(e)}
                           ref={this.inputRef}
                           onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                         {this.state.contentValue}  
                      </div>
                 )
        
              }
    }
```